# Прошу совет: "Возможности виртуализации *.exe в Linux".

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, linux

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с непониманием в решении следующей проблемы: необходимо запустить несколько win-приложений в Linux. Попытки использовать wine пока дают неудовлетворительные результаты, т.к. у *.exe-шников много зависимостей (одно приложение, например, требует .Net FrameWork и FlashPlayer 11, другое - ActiveX-надстройку под IE). Задача очень нетривиальная, но, может, у кого-нибудь есть опыт "извращений", например, ThinApp + Wine?

Comment: Вы пробовали mono для первого? Насколько мне известно, flash player и IE работают под wine.. Active X тоже должно работать... правда наверное не с mono.

Answer (score 1):

Аналогичные проблемы успешно решал используя вышеупомянутый *wine*, устанавливая требующиеся зависимости при помощи *winetricks*.

Comment: Вы не поверите, всегда делал то же самое, пока не появилась необходимость взаимодействия .Net + Flash 11 + потоковое видео. Fail, как вы понимаете, именно с Flash Player 11.